# How to import a wordpress extended rss xml file to mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a cms website where I need to import wordpress extended rss file to my mysql database using php. I am also using phpmyadmin for this.

Comment: What you did till now?

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you're asking, but it is normal practice here to show a bit more detail than that. I don't think someone could help on the basis of this information.